# Solspace User Login Form - Custom Error page

Tags: members, solspace-user

I can't get the "error page" parameter to work with the Solspace login form. 
https://solspace.com/expressionengine/user/docs/error_page/

Anyone know if it is supported by the login form? See my code below:

```
{exp:member:login_form 
    return="{last_page_visited}" 
    error_page="site/login-error"}
```

If not, any other suggestions outside of the "Custom System Msgs" module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because User does not have it's own login template and uses the native EE login form, therefore any User parameters, such as error_page, won't function there.
https://solspace.com/expressionengine/user/docs/login/
"User does not have it's own Login template tag, as the ExpressionEngine Login_Form tag is pretty sufficient."

Comment: Thanks Jim. 

What about the module, Simple Registration?  Has anyone use that. is that using native Member functionality not a channel?  Says it supports inline errors.

Comment: If I am reading it correctly, it just works with Registration form, and it makes its own template tag for it, like User does. As far as I can see, they don't do anything with the Login form.

Comment: I just bought SR, and look it does return the error messages in json format.


[link](http://wedoaddons.com/addon/simple-registration/documentation)


'Use the parameter ajax="y" and you'll get error/success responses in JSON format. Simple Registration will even return an array with the fields that were errorneous and some info about them - enabling you to display the message next to the field where the problem is.'

Comment: Pretty sure that's referring to the Register form... :)